# How to stop a process permanently for every session?

Tags: gnome, process-management

I have a laptop with minimal resources and this process, "gnome-software", takes up huge space in RAM. I have to kill it every time.

Is there permanent way to stop this process?

Comment: In addition to uninstalling `gnome-software` as in dr_'s answer, you might want to consider switching to a less resource-intensive desktop environment than Gnome, like [xfce](https://www.xfce.org/) or [lxde](http://www.lxde.org/)

Comment: @cas  thanks, will try that out.

Comment: @cas is it possible to have two user accounts with different desktop environments

Comment: yes, it is possible.  depending on your display manager (e.g. gdm3, lightdm, sddm, slim, etc) it's also possible to choose a different DE when you login (either just for the current login session, or to change your default).

Comment: @cas I did that and after login , nothing was clickable in lxfe dm and it wasn't even opening terminal. Xdm made my display disappeared. I decided I am ok with gdm right now as I don't want nightmares. Moreover in gdm I can navigate my workspace with only mouse  . I am ok with gdm right now. Thanks for suggestion cas.

Comment: i didn't say you had to change your display manager.  I said that some display managers allow you to choose which desktop environment to use when you login.   they will offer a choice from those which are installed.

Comment: @cas Changing to lxde from settings during login does work (LXDE, Openbox and ubuntu is shown and not xfce). Great, now there is an approximate 400Mb extra space for me which is nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gnome-software` is the GNOME frontend to the PackageKit, a GUI utility to install and update packages. If it bothers you, you can uninstall it via

```
apt-get remove gnome-software
```

and install/update software via CLI using `apt-get`.

Comment: Thanks, it went away